# Input should be equal to a list, but isn't

Tags: python, list, input

A friend gave me the idea to write a program that asks you English words and you have to translate them in German and reverse.

So the program asks a word and checks the input if it matches the actual translation.

So the user gives an input of which Unit he/she wants to study. This input is stored in a variable. Now I have a list of the words of Unit 1. Then the program randomly chooses a word in the List. This word is then printed and the user enters his answer. Then using .index I find the position of the word asked and search for the same position in a second list.

My problem is that the Unit input is seen as a string instead of being one of the lists I made. So then the user just gets asked for letter from this input.

I want to somehow have this input equal the name of a list I have and work.(The Lists are actually larger, I cut them so it is a little easier to read)

The code is here:

```
import random

U1_E = ["consider (sb) to be …","describe (sb) as ...","proud to + infinitive"
    ]
U1_D = ["erachten, wähnen","erachten, wähnen","beschreiben"
    ]
U5_E = ["confortable","crowded","delicious","efficient","fashionable",
    ]                                                      
U5_D = ["bequem","überfüllt","köstlich","effizient","modisch"
    ]                                                       
Num = ["first","second","third","forth","fifth","sixth","7th","8th","9th",
    ]                                                     
Unit_Eng = ["U1_E","U2_E","U3_E","U4_E","U5_E","U6_E","U7_E","U8_E"
    ]                                                       
good_points = 0                                            
bad_points = 0                                              
Name_of_Agent = input("Can you please give me your name?")  
Select_Unit = input(Name_of_Agent + ",which Unit would you like to train?    [Ux_E/Ux_D]")  
Num_of_Words = int(input("How many words would you like?")) 


if (Select_Unit in Unit_Eng):
    for i in range(0,Num_of_Words):                             
        Word_E = random.choice(Select_Unit)                    
        Select_Unit_oposite = Select_Unit[:3] + "D"             
        Word_D = Select_Unit_oposite[Select_Unit.index(Word_E)] 
        if (input("The "+Num[i]+" Word is:"+Word_E+":") == Word_D):      
            print("Well done, you got it right!")               
            good_points = good_points + 1                      
        else:
            print("The word you gave is wrong, the right answer is:",   Word_D)    
            bad_points = bad_points + 1                                       
    print("Your total score is:",good_points-    bad_points)                       


input("Press Enter to close the program")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that you are trying to use `Select_Unit` as the list rather than the *name* of the list you want to access.

There are a few different ways to implement this, and you should experiment with different ways if you want to push your Python knowledge further.

A way that comes to mind off the bat would be to store the units in a Python dictionary of lists rather than a series of lists, this would allow you to immediately access the value (the unit) behind a unit name once you have verified that it exists in your units.

It might look something like the following

```
units = {"unit_1": ["word_1", "word_2", ...], "unit_2": ...}
# get input including the unit they want
if unit in units:
    chosen_unit = units[unit]
    # continue to do whatever you need to extract the information now that you have the chosen unit.
```